# Load assets in webview with phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, cordova, uiwebview

I can't seem to find an answer for this on the Cordova site or any where else for that matter. In you webview thru Phonegap is it possible to load javascript files & css files that are local to the file being loaded in the webview?

For example I have an html page, mysite.com/nativeview.html in that page has 3 dependent file, style.css, jquery.js and lib.js all of them are located on the mysite.com server. Can I load mysite.com/nativeview.html into the webview of my app and have the dependent files loaded in along with it?

I can get my pages loaded into the webview but there are no styles or javascript applied.

Comment: It should work. Did you whitelist your domain?

Comment: All domains are whitelisted using *

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to create symlinks to the dependent files.
You can symlink the individual file or folder using

`ln -s source target`

or you can symlink the contents of a directory and not folders using `lndir`

As long as all files are in on www folder and the sources of the symlinks are not moved then you should be fine. Ideally www would be inside another folder, say src or mobile-commons to accommodate the fact that other testing environments, e.g. Xcode or eclipse (for android) may not be able to see the www folder, in which case you would have to specify the location of all resources relative to src/mobile-commons instead of www.